# Need a help in understanding a part of theorem7.1 in chapter2 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The theorem is given in the following picture:

[image]

But it is not clear for me from where the term $<\psi_{j},\phi_{j}>$ in the determinant come. could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: I think they are basis vectors for the domain space and range spaces.

Comment: yes I know .... but how this term come to the determinant, this is my question.@user247327

Comment: $(<\psi_j,\psi_i>)$ is the matrix of the linear transformation K with respect to the bases $\{\phi_i\}$ and $\{\psi_i\}$. The statement here is that I-K is a non -singular transformation if and only if its matrix is non-singular.